# Mounting a blu-ray disk on arch linux

Tags: mount, arch-linux, vlc-media-player, blu-ray

I'm trying to mount a blu-ray disk on arch linux and so far I'm failing. According to google, my reader is capable of reading blu-ray and wodim also detects the device.

```
$ wodim dev=/dev/sr0 -prcap
```

gives me the device.

When I enter

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

it gives me
`mount: /cdrom: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

I've read somewhere that I need to specify the filesystem type but

```
$ sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

gives me `mount: /cdrom: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`  as well.

I've tried following other guides which tell me to install aacs codes (which I did) by putting a keydb.cfg file inside `~/.config/aacs`. This file also contains the keys to my blu-ray disk (a movie called Cloud Atlas).

Am I overseeing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an UTF filesystem, you need the udftools package. Use `wrudf /dev/sr0` to open an interactive shell which will give you some commands operating on an existing UDF filesystem.

Comment: First it says `permission denied` so naturally I sudo'ed it and it says `Read discinfo failed`

Comment: Please have a look on the output of "dmesg", just after the insertion of the disc.

Comment: No changes from before and after inserting the disc.

Comment: The drive is probably not recognized well. Locate your drive: wodim -scanbus then, as user root: inxi --optical -xxxx. What is the output ?